# Create Active Directory Group with '#' as the first character in its name by using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory-group

I want to create a new Active Directory Group and use '#' as the first character in its name. but i got a exception message said an invalid 'dn' in my C# code. I know that '#' is a special character in powershell script, then I escape '#' with single quote, no exception from my C# code, and the new Active Directory Group also created successfully. But the single quote is also displayed in board of Active Directory.

```
string name = "#ABC";
public void Create(string ouPath, string name)
{
    if (!DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://CN=" + name + "," + ouPath))
    {
         try
         {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ouPath);
            DirectoryEntry group = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + name, "group");
            group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = name;
            group.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    else { Console.WriteLine(path + " already exists"); }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZm4G.png)

Is there anyone can help me to create Active Directory Group with '#' as the first character in its name?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `#` is not allowed as the first character of a DN or CN. This is a restriction of Active Directory.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366101.aspx) for reserved characters.

As mentioned at the end of the linked article, you will have to escape the `#` with a backslash (`\`) instead of a single quote.
Note that in C# backslashes in strings are escaped by another backslash. So your group name string should look like that:

```
string name = "\\#ABC"; 
string ouPath = // your ou path
Create(ouPath, name);
```

**Update:** Another way to escape reserved characters is via backslash and hexadecimal ascii code, which is `0x23` for `#`. So the string in your example should be:

```
string name = "\\23ABC";
```

Comment: Thanks Vogt, your reply making me understand that associating the '#' to powershell is wrong. But using double backslashes not work either.

Comment: @simon updated my answer, last try, if this doesn't work, I can't help you.

Comment: I have tried it also, but it not worked yet. I thank you very much for your prompt reply, Vogt.

Comment: @vogt, It's my fault. I make a simple mistake while using your code, your solution is work fine, thank you very much.